# jqTree appendNode function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, jqtree

I have the following issue. The tree has some nodes. Using function 'addNodeAfter' I add new node. Then using function 'appendNode' I add child node to just added node. After this I try to move my child node to another, but I can't. Only after some attempts it starts working. A tried to debug and found out that 'event.move_info.target_node' is root node (the whole tree). Why could that occur?